# How can I restrict applications on having Internet access?

Tags: ubuntu

How do I restrict programs from accessing the Internet in Ubuntu. Not by port, but by application.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless each application runs under a different User ID, in that case you can drop the packets by userID.

Comment: it is very much possible with a good firewall.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **firejail**. It runs the application in sandbox where you control if the application could see the network or the file system. Example:

```
firejail --net=none firefox
```

This will execute Firefox browser without internet access.
Note that the firejail distribution in the Ubuntu repo is *outdated* - better download its latest LTS version from the firejail home page.

Additional information about firejail usage - [here](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/).

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is referred to as an "application based firewall". Googling for that doesn't turn up anything currently useful for Ubuntu (or Linux in general). There used to be one called TuxGuardian but it appears to have been abandoned back in 2006 (don't attempt to use it).

However, it is possible to block applications from accessing the network by using AppArmor and creating profiles for the application(s) you want to block. Note that I'm not aware of any "user-friendly" GUIs for configuring AppArmor on Ubuntu - its strictly a text editor and command line operation so if you're new to Linux you may want to avoid this.

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) is the Ubuntu community page for AppArmor to get you started.

[Here](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/ProfileLanguage#Network_rules) are the rules you are going to want to use in your profile(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use network namespaces for that. For example:

```
sudo ip netns add empty
sudo ip netns exec empty sudo -u "$USER" firefox
```

…would launch Firefox as the current user but without any network access. That's because all namespaces start out empty, meaning they have no network interface assigned to it by default.

That's actually what Firejail does for you.